# How to controlling Apollo query cache to serve cached data and check server for updates

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

I'm reading documentation and I can't figure out how to control [apollo-cache-persist](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist) (or perhaps I need another library for this). I need two things:

1. I need to save all data I query with `@client` flag and load it from
   cache.
2. When requesting data from server I need to give locally stored cache first, but then check for any new data that server has.

I thought that second part worked almost out of the box, this was one of the points that many resources mentioned how smart Apollo is with caching and fetching data. But now that I'm trying it out myself I can't find a way to do this.